# displaying server error messages on UI in php

Tags: php

I am very new to php programming. I have written a sign up html file where the user enters his email and password. If the user has already registered, I am redirecting to sign-in screen and if the user is new use, I am persisting in the database. Now if the user enters wrong password, he will again be redirected to sign-in screen but this time I want to show a message on the screen, that the password entered is incorrect. The sign in screen should not display the message when the user navigates directly to the sign in screen.

The code snippet is shown below:

```
    <?php 
      define('DB_HOST', 'hostname');
      define('DB_NAME', 'db_name'); 
      define('DB_USER','username');
      define('DB_PASSWORD','password');
      $con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " .  mysql_error()); 

      $db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

      function NewUser() { 
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password']; 
        $query = "INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers (email,pass) VALUES ('$email','$password')"; 

        $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error()); 
        if($data) { 
          header('Location: reg-success.html'); 
        }
      }

      function SignUp() { 
        if(!empty($_POST['email'])){ 
          $emailQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers WHERE email = '$_POST[email]'"); 
          if($row = mysql_fetch_array($emailQuery)) { 
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' AND pass =  '$_POST[password]'");
           if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
              echo 'validated user. screen that is accessible to a registered user';
           }else{
            echo 'Redirect to the sign in screen with error message';
           }
         }else{
          NewUser();
         }
        } 
      }
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    SignUp();
}
?>
```

Please let me know how to get this implementation using php

Comment: Unrelated note: Your code is *wide open* to SQL injection attacks.  You might want to start reading here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: a simple solution would be to pass the error message in the query string like `?error=1&message=Invalid%20Login`

Then check `$_GET` params

Comment: Use `exit;` after header location change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of classes that may help you prevent injection hacks plus get you going on how to do what you are trying to do in general. If you create classes for your tasks, it will be easier to re-use what your code elsewhere. I personally like the PDO method to connect and grab info from a DB (you will want to look up "binding" to help further prevent injection attacks), but this will help get the basics down. This is all very rough and you would want to expand out to create some error reporting and more usable features.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    // Create a simple DB engine
    class DBEngine
        {
            protected   $con;
            // Create a default database element
            public  function __construct($host = '',$db = '',$user = '',$pass = '')
                {
                    try {
                            $this->con  =   new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
                        }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                          return 0;
                        }
                }

            // Simple fetch and return method
            public  function Fetch($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();

                    if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                            $rows   =   $query->fetchAll();
                        }

                    return (isset($rows) && $rows !== 0 && !empty($rows))? $rows: 0;
                }

            // Simple write to db method
            public  function Write($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();
                }
        }

    // Your user controller class
    class   UserControl
        {
            public  $_error;
            protected   $db;
            // Save the database connection object for use in this class
            public  function __construct($db)
                {
                    $this->_error   =   array();
                    $this->db       =   $db;
                }

            // Add user to DB
            protected function Add()
                {
                    $email      =   htmlentities($_POST['email'],ENT_QUOTES);
                    // Provided you have a php version that supports better encryption methods, use that
                    // but you should do at least a very basic password encryption.
                    $password   =   hash('sha512',$_POST['password']);
                    // Use our handy DBEngine writer method to write your sql
                    $this->db->Write("INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers (`email`,`pass`) VALUES ('$email','$password')");
                }

            // Fetch user from DB
            protected   function Fetch($_email = '')
                {
                    $_email     =   htmlentities($_email,ENT_QUOTES);
                    $password   =   hash('sha512',$_POST['password']);
                    // Use our handy DBEngine fetcher method to check your db
                    $_user      =   $this->db->Fetch("SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers WHERE email = '$_email' and password = '$password'");
                    // Return true if not 0
                    return  ($_user !== 0)? 1:0;
                }

            // Simple fetch user or set user method
            public  function execute()
                {
                    // Check that email is a valid format
                    if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            // Save the true/false to error reporting
                            $this->_error['user']['in_db']  =   $this->Fetch($_POST['email']);
                            // Asign short variable
                            $_check =   $this->_error['user']['in_db'];

                            if($_check !== 1) {
                                    // Add user if not in system
                                    $this->Add();
                                    // You'll want to expand your add feature to include error reporting
                                    // This is just returning that it made it to this point
                                    $this->_error['user']['add_db'] =   1;
                                }
                            else {
                                    // Run some sort of login script
                                }
                            // Good email address
                            $this->_error['email']['validate']  =   1;
                        }
                    else
                        // Bad email address
                        $this->_error['email']['validate']  =   0;
                }
        }

//  $_POST['submit']    =   true;
//  $_POST['email']     =   'jenkybad<script>email';
//  $_POST['password']  =   'mypassword';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // Set up a db connection
        $db     =   new DBEngine('hostname','dbname','dbuser','dbpass');
        // Create instance of your user control
        $_user  =   new UserControl($db);
        // Execute instance
        $_user->execute();

        // Check for basic erroring
        print_r($_user->_error);
    } ?>
```